# how to calculate p value of 2 sample

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

James and Margaret grow watermelons. Margaret claims her watermelons are heavier than James's watermelons. $40$ sample has been taken from both.

James: mean $7.3$ variance $0.4$
Margaret mean $11.3$ variance $2.8$

which test statistic should i use? 
I'm looking at 2 sample proportion test right now . 
and how should I make the assumptions?

$H_0= J\geq M$

$H_a= M < J $